# DB2 9.5 . Select distinct values from first column , but seeing 2 other columns values

Tags: db2

I have a single table with 80,000+ rows (tag feeds) of which I have 12 distinct tags (TagID) so I only want to return 12 rows.

I want to find the latest value for each tagid based on the (MAX) date column. So really I want a DISTINCT on the tagid and make sure I have the record for the newest date and display the tagid, date and location columns

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date, tagid, location
FROM table a
WHERE date = (
    SELECT MAX(date)
    FROM table b
    WHERE a.key1 = b.key1
      AND a.key2 = b.key2
      -- etc
)
```

Will get you what you want.  I'm guessing that `WHERE a.tagid = b.tagid` will probably be the WHERE clause you want, but if there are other columns that make the row unique, you may need to include those as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to produce the desired results without connecting all the key columns in a subquery:

```
WITH x AS ( 
     SELECT datecol, 
         tagid, 
         location, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY tagid ORDER BY datecol DESC ) AS rnum
     FROM sometable
)
SELECT datecol, tagid, location FROM x WHERE rnum = 1
;
```